# 401 when adding customer with QB Online API v3

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I keep getting a 401 when I try to add a customer with QB Online API v3. The xml works in the API Explorer, and I'm able to query customers from my program. I just can't POST. What am I doing wrong?

```
        string reqBody = "<Customer xmlns=\"http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3\" domain=\"QBO\" sparse=\"false\"><DisplayName>Empire Records</DisplayName>"
                + "<BillAddr><Line1>201 S King St</Line1><City>Seattle</City><CountrySubDivisionCode>WA</CountrySubDivisionCode><PostalCode>98104</PostalCode></BillAddr>"
                + "<PrimaryPhone><FreeFormNumber>425-867-5309</FreeFormNumber></PrimaryPhone><PrimaryEmailAddr><Address>helpme@thefly.con</Address></PrimaryEmailAddr></Customer>";

        IConsumerRequest req = session.Request();
        req = req.Post().WithRawContentType("application/xml").WithRawContent(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reqBody));
        req.AcceptsType = "application/xml";
        string response = req.Post().ForUrl("https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/" + realmID + "/customer").ToString()
```

Comment: You can try this call using devkit and capture the request header using any http snooper like fiddler. Then you can compare that header with the same from above. That might help you to debug this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Good call... The auth header is missing. I tried adding SignWithToken() but that didn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext1 = new OAuthConsumerContext 
{ 
ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"].ToString(), 
SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1, 
ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"].ToString() 
};  

OAuthSession oSession1 = new OAuthSession(consumerContext1,     "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token", 
"https://workplace.intuit.com/Connect/Begin", 
"https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token"); 

oSession1.ConsumerContext.UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps (I think). But now I'm getting various other errors (500, 400...). I think I'm not setting the body and content type right. This should only be a few lines of code. Can somebody just walk me through everything that's needed to get a POST to work?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I was doing a Post() AND a ReadBody() (after trying a bunch of different things), which was executing the request twice. So the customer was being inserted, but then the error occurred on the ReadBody() because it was a duplicate. But I was doing this based on an example I found online, so it's not my fault. Really.